# WebAPi - CORS in Firefox and chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, cors

Can you please help me on how do I enable CORS in FireFox and Chrome. The WebAPi is working fine with Internet but not with Chrome/Firefox.

This is what I am getting in firefox console.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at `http://localhost:51/api/abcservice/M2`. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

CORS is not browser dependent, you must enable it server-side.

Install CORS WebApi NuGet package :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Then at application start :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // CORS
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

[Source](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors)

Comment: thanks Florian, this is all done, including decorating controller with  [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]. But no luck.

Comment: Did you try with * in origin ?

Comment: You need to specify parameter for EnableCors() otherwise the server will assume the default value (possible null). After I added below variable it works as global without configure at controller level.
    config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"));

Answer (score 0):

With Web API, sometime you get the CORS error when your request encounter an exception on the server side, so make sure that you debug the request on the Web API controller, and double check that the origin header is set to the response.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely IE and Edge, Chrome and Firefox make an additional OPTIONS request before each GET or POST, that's why you should configure the attribute for it explicitly in the global.asax. Try this code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("access-control-allow-origin", "*");

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "options") 
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("access-control-allow-methods", "post, put, delete, get");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("access-control-allow-headers", "content-type, accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("access-control-max-age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
}
```